# I need to add a user in express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have a user model, which has a table in the db:

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';
import bcryptjs from 'bcryptjs';

export default class User extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        username: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          defaultValue: '',
          validate: {
            len: {
              args: [3, 40],
              msg: 'User must have between 3 and 40 characters',
            },
          },
        },
        email: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          defaultValue: '',
          unique: {
            msg: 'Email already exists',
          },
          validate: {
            isEmail: {
              msg: 'invalid email',
            },
            isUnique(value, next) {
              User.findOne({ where: { email: value } })
                .then((user) => {
                  if (user) {
                    return next('email already exists, try another');
                  }
                  return next();
                })
                .catch((err) => next(err));
            },
          },
        },
        password_hash: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          defaultValue: '',
        },
        password: {
          type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
          defaultValue: '',
          validate: {
            len: {
              args: [6, 8],
              msg: 'The password must be between 6 and 8 characters long',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      { sequelize },
    );

    this.addHook('beforeSave', async (user) => {
      if (user.password) {
        user.password_hash = await bcryptjs.hash(user.password, 8);
      }
    });

    return this;
  }

  passwordIsValid(password) {
    return bcryptjs.compare(password, this.password_hash);
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsToMany(models.Photo, models.Message, models.Contact, { foreignKey: ['user_id', 'user_idm', 'userId'] });
  }
}
```

I have a contacts model, which has a table in the db, where a logged in user will need to add another user with their name and email:

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export default class Contact extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        userId: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: false,
          references: {
            model: 'users',
            key: 'id',
          },
        },
        userEmail: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
        },
        userUsername: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
        },
      },
      {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'contacts',
      },
    );
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
  }
}
```

I have to join one user to another, but when I use the function it only returns this: "Internal server error", look at the controller here:

```
import Contact from '../models/Contact';
import User from '../models/User';

class ContactController {
  async store(req, res) {
    try {
      const { username, email } = req.body;

      const user = await User.findByPk(req.userId);

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: ['User does not exist'],
        });
      }

      const isContactAdd = await Contact.findOne({
        where: {
          userId: user.id,
          userEmail: email,
        },
      });

      if (isContactAdd) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: ['User already added'],
        });
      }

      const contact = await User.findOne({
        where: {
          email,
        },
      });

      if (!contact) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          errors: ['Contact not found'],
        });
      }

      await Contact.create({
        userId: user.id,
        userEmail: email,
        userUsername: username,
      });
      return res.json({ message: 'Friend added successfully' });
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: ['Internal server error'],
      });
    }
  }
}

export default new ContactController();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block, add **console.log(e);** to log the error in your console and track where the error is coming from.

You can also add parameter validation to your controller to ensure that the request doesn't miss the parameters 'username' and 'email' and handle the error in this case. If the parameters are missed and your model's create method is called without these necessary params, it can throw an error and be caught in the catch block.

```js
const { username, email } = req.body;

if (!username || !email) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        error: {
            message: "Both username and email are required.",
        }
    });
}
```

*P.S: Just to note, when it's an Internal Server Error, don't use the 400 status code (indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error). The range for internal server errors is 5XX; use 500 instead of 400.*